# Typescript parameters: Any at the end of a string parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

So, I was learning typescript but I don't understand how these parameters work

```
interface MyInterface {
   (name?: string): any;
   new (name?: string): any;
}

class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    (name?: string): any; // This is not working
}
```

**What I understand:** `name` should be a string parameter, not mandatory

**What I don't understand:** How does that outdide `any` work? And what does `new name` mean?

Source: [Angular core documentation for OutputDecorator](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/core/src/metadata/directives.ts#L836):

Comment: that interface seems to describe a function that takes a string and returns anything (that's what the :any part means). But it must also be a class that can be initialized via a constructor (the new part). It's really hard to get that done via typescript alone, but there are js constructs that could match it.

Answer (score 0):

Those are *call signatures* and *construct signatures*.

Anything that has the type `MyInterface` as you've defined it can be

- Called, optionally with a `string` argument.
- Constructed (`new`-ed), optionally with a `string` argument.

In both cases, a calling or a `new`-ing a `MyInterface` will result in a value of type `any`.

---

As for this:

```
class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    (name?: string): any; // This is not working
}
```

A call or construct signature can only occur in a *TypeBody* as per [the TypeScript spec](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/9fec77551c25a0c7930f84cfd10d4d71b866268b/doc/spec.md#383-object-type-literals). A type body is only used in object type literals and [interface declarations](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/9fec77551c25a0c7930f84cfd10d4d71b866268b/doc/spec.md#a5-interfaces). This is subtly different from a *ClassBody* which doesn't permit call/construct signatures.

In a class, you can instead define a constructor:

```
class C {
    constructor() {
        console.log("Hi");
    }
}
```

But there's no way to make a class callable.

Note that implementing something with a call and construct signature means that *the instance* will get the type, not the static side. In other words, you're saying that the thing that `MyClass` produces will be compatible with `MyInterface`, but nothing about the static shape of `MyClass` itself.

There is no way to ensure that the static side has a certain shape right now except for something like this hack:

```
class MyClass {
    // ...
}

if (!!false) {
    let x: MyInterface = MyClass;
}
```